# How to collapse a menu on loading the page

Tags: javascript

Been using this javascript code to make my lists clickable to collapse but when I load the page with it attached it seems to expand the lists on loading. My question is with the javascript code is it possible to make it collapse apon page load so users have to click the text to expand it.
Heres the full code with the javascript

```html
<UL id="example_tree">
   <LI><span><strong>A</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Aimees Travel.Html">Aimees Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Airport Parking.Html">Airport Parking</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Bolton.html">Arriva  Bolton</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Winsford.html">Arriva  Winsford</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Wythenshawe.html">Arriva  Wythenshawe</a></p></span></LI>
  </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>B</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Bakers.Html">Bakers Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Belle Vue.Html">Belle Vue</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Bullocks.html">Bullocks Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
 <LI><span><strong>C</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Cheshire Council.html">Cheshire Council</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Chesters Executive Travel.html">Chesters Executive Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Copelands.html">Copelands</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>D</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../D&G.Html">D&amp;G</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>E</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Eavesway.html">Eavesway</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Edwards Coaches.html">Edwards Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Ellisons Travel.html">Ellisons Travel</a></p</span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>F</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="First Potteries.html">First Potteries</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><p><a href="Flight Shuttle Services.html">Flight Shuttle Services</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>G</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../GHA.Html">GHA Group</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><<p><a href="Go Goodwins.html">Go Goodwins</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Golden Green.Html">Golden Green Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Grayway.html">Grayway</a></p></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>H</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Happy Days Coaches.html">Happy Days Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Bowers Coaches.Html">High Peak</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Hollinshead Coaches.Html">Hollinshead Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><a href="../../Holmeswood.Html">Holmeswood Group</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>I</Strong></span>
  <UL>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>J</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Jones Coaches.Html">Jones Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>K</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Kt's Coaches.html">Kt's Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>L</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Lambs.Html">Lambs</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Leons Coaches.html">Leons Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>M</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Manchester Airport.Html">Manchester Airport Group</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../MCT.Html">Manchester Community Transport</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Maynes Coaches.html">Maynes Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Megabus.html">Megabus</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>N</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>O</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>P</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Parks of Hamilton.html">Parks of Hamilton</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Pauls Coaches.html">Pauls of Stoke</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Q</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>R</span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Robin Hood Travel.html">Robin Hood Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Roy McCarthy Coaches.Html">Roy McCarthy Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>S</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Scraggs.html">Scraggs</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Selwyns Travel.Html">Selwyns Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span> <p><a href="../../Shearings.Html">Shearings</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Smiths of Marple.html">Smiths of Marple</a></p></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="South Lancs.html">South Lancs Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Stagecoach Manchester.html">Stagecoach Manchester</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="../../Stanways.Html">Stanways Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><p><a href="Stotts Tours.html">Stotts</a></p></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Swans Travel.html">Swans Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>T</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Terravision.html">Terravision</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Transdev Burnley & Pendle.html">Transdev Burnley &amp; Pendle</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Transdev Lancashire United.html">Transdev Lancashire United</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Travellers Choice.html">Travellers Choice</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>U</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="UK Coachways.html">UK Coachways</a></p></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>V</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>W</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>X</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Y</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Yelloway.html">Yelloway</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Z</Strong></span>
  <UL>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
   </LI>
  </UL>
 </LI>
</UL>
<script type="text/javascript">
var allSpan = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
for(var i = 0; i < allSpan.length; i++){
 allSpan[i].onclick=function(){
  if(this.parentNode){
   var childList = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('UL');
   for(var j = 0; j< childList.length;j++){
    var currentState = childList[j].style.display;
    if(currentState=="none"){
     childList[j].style.display="block";
    }else{
     childList[j].style.display="none";
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Basically as you can see with the Javascript running the page loads with the lists expanded but I want them closed apon loading if its possible so users click the letters to expand and see the lists under it. Some have suggested that I need CSS code also to go along wit it to fix my issue but I want to try it with the javascript code first before adding extra code in other places

Comment: It is better to set the <li>s to display:none is CSS. If you want to do it through javascript, then you have to iterate through <li>s and set to display none explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You would rather hide list items with CSS by default. For this you would then need to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) since there is no `style.display` property set explicitly initially.

```css
#example_tree > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<UL id="example_tree">
   <LI><span><strong>A</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Aimees Travel.Html">Aimees Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Airport Parking.Html">Airport Parking</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Bolton.html">Arriva  Bolton</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Winsford.html">Arriva  Winsford</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Arriva Wythenshawe.html">Arriva  Wythenshawe</a></p></span></LI>
  </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>B</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Bakers.Html">Bakers Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Belle Vue.Html">Belle Vue</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Bullocks.html">Bullocks Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
 <LI><span><strong>C</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Cheshire Council.html">Cheshire Council</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Chesters Executive Travel.html">Chesters Executive Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Copelands.html">Copelands</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>D</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../D&G.Html">D&amp;G</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>E</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Eavesway.html">Eavesway</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Edwards Coaches.html">Edwards Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Ellisons Travel.html">Ellisons Travel</a></p</span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>F</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="First Potteries.html">First Potteries</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><p><a href="Flight Shuttle Services.html">Flight Shuttle Services</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>G</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../GHA.Html">GHA Group</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><<p><a href="Go Goodwins.html">Go Goodwins</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Golden Green.Html">Golden Green Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Grayway.html">Grayway</a></p></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>H</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Happy Days Coaches.html">Happy Days Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Bowers Coaches.Html">High Peak</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Hollinshead Coaches.Html">Hollinshead Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><a href="../../Holmeswood.Html">Holmeswood Group</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>I</Strong></span>
  <UL>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>J</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Jones Coaches.Html">Jones Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>K</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Kt's Coaches.html">Kt's Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>L</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Lambs.Html">Lambs</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Leons Coaches.html">Leons Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                             </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>M</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Manchester Airport.Html">Manchester Airport Group</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../MCT.Html">Manchester Community Transport</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Maynes Coaches.html">Maynes Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Megabus.html">Megabus</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>N</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>O</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>P</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Parks of Hamilton.html">Parks of Hamilton</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Pauls Coaches.html">Pauls of Stoke</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Q</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>R</span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Robin Hood Travel.html">Robin Hood Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Roy McCarthy Coaches.Html">Roy McCarthy Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>S</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Scraggs.html">Scraggs</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="../../Selwyns Travel.Html">Selwyns Travel</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span> <p><a href="../../Shearings.Html">Shearings</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Smiths of Marple.html">Smiths of Marple</a></p></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="South Lancs.html">South Lancs Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Stagecoach Manchester.html">Stagecoach Manchester</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="../../Stanways.Html">Stanways Coaches</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><p><a href="Stotts Tours.html">Stotts</a></p></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Swans Travel.html">Swans Travel</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>T</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Terravision.html">Terravision</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Transdev Burnley & Pendle.html">Transdev Burnley &amp; Pendle</a></p></span></LI>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Transdev Lancashire United.html">Transdev Lancashire United</a></p></span></LI>
                        <LI><span><p><a href="Travellers Choice.html">Travellers Choice</a></p></span></LI>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>U</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="UK Coachways.html">UK Coachways</a></p></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>V</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>W</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>X</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Y</Strong></span>
  <UL>
   <LI><span><p><a href="Yelloway.html">Yelloway</a></p></span></LI>
   
                          </UL>
 </LI>
<LI><span><strong>Z</Strong></span>
  <UL>
                          </UL>
 </LI>
   </LI>
  </UL>
 </LI>
</UL>
<script type="text/javascript">
var allSpan = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
for(var i = 0; i < allSpan.length; i++){
 allSpan[i].onclick=function(){
  if(this.parentNode){
   
          var childList = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('UL');
   
          for(var j = 0; j< childList.length;j++){
    var currentState = window.getComputedStyle(childList[j], null).display;
    if (currentState == "none"){
     childList[j].style.display = "block";
    } else {
     childList[j].style.display = "none";
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use [jQuery's toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method. The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements. Its usage can be found in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp) as well.

Or you might use the jQuery Accordion to achieve your goal.Here are the links:
1.[Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)
2. If want to learn about accordion [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exactly-how-to-create-a-custom-jquery-accordion--net-2690)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add before the end of your script :

```
var allUL = document.getElementsByTagName('UL');
for(var i = 0; i < allUL.length; i++){
  allUL[i].style.display="none";
}
```